# How to change the back arrow of SearchView programmatically?

Tags: android, searchview

I want to programmatically change the color of back arrow of SearchView. Is it possible in Android? If yes, how to achieve it?

I can change the back arrow of SearchView in XML as follows, but I want to do it programmatically.

```
app:collapseIcon="@drawable/back_arrow"
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(R.drawable.icon)` . `app:collapseIcon` is for `ToolBar`.

Answer (score 3):

you can directly set background image for back arrow from drawable

```
back_arrow.setBackgroundResources(R.drawable.back_arrow_changed);
```

Comment: and how to geet back_arrow instance?

Comment: you can find id of your imageview

Comment: back_arrow =(ImageView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_mag_icon);

Comment: `search_mag_icon` is search icon which appear on the search bar

Comment: It is not possible to change the back arrow color of searchView on runtime as it is not exposed by Android. Need to create custom view like searchView.